# Ubuntu 20.04.1 Server, bonded network interfaces, keepalived not working

Tags: networking, server

I setup bonded network interfaces to provide greater HA for a HaProxy (HaProxy is a linux load balancer) setup with `keepalived` on two Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS servers.  The bonded network interfaces setup with netplan are working properly and setup with `keepalived`.  However, `keepalived` does not treat the master and backup nodes of the `keepalived` cluster properly and both show as Master.

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
   version: 2
   ethernets:
     eth0:
      dhcp4: true
     eth1: 
      dhcp4: false
     eth2: 
      dhcp4: false
   bonds:
    bond0:
     dhcp4: false
     interfaces:
        - eth1
        - eth2
     parameters:
       mode: active-backup
       primary: eth1
     addresses: 
         - 192.168.0.6/24
     nameservers: 
       addresses: 
         - 192.168.0.1
```

---

```
vrrp_instance VI_01 {
    state MASTER
    interface bond0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 101
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.0.10/24
    }
```

---

```
vrrp_instance VI_01 {
    state BACKUP
    interface bond0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.0.10/24
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,

Leo

Comment: Need more details. What is "HA" and "HaProxy"? How about a copy of your netplan .yaml files?

Comment: HaProxy is a linux load balancer.  Here is my yaml file:  https://pastebin.com/UCjW7TGx  keepalived master:  https://pastebin.com/D4rzQTFS  keepalived backup:  https://pastebin.com/JJ5axRaY

Comment: I don't know much about keepalived, but in looking at your master/backup scripts, you've assigned virtual_router_id and virtual_ipaddress, the same values. That doesn't look right.

Comment: That is the way the keepalived should be setup.  Both the master and the backup configs have the same route ids and virtual ip but diffferent priorities.  This means that the Master (as it has the higher priority) will be the Master for the keepalived configuration and host the virtual ip address.  If it goes done, the backup hosts that ip address.  However, with a bonded interface, this is not working as the mac addresses for the bonded interfaces cannot be properly recognized by keepalived to determine which server is the master or the backup.

Comment: Ah! Use the `match:` and `macaddress:` stanzas on the physical ethernet devices in your netplan .yaml.

Comment: See my partial answer.

Comment: Minor edits to my .yaml text

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

After trying a solution, which entailed added mac addresses to the netplan configuration, I found that the same issue with keepalived was occurring, which was that both machines were showing up as the master.  Further investigation showed that the mac address using for the bonded interface on both servers was identical, which ended up being the problem.

By changing the name of the bonded interface in netplan on the second server, to bond1 (rather then bond0), then using that name  in the keepalived config file solved the issue, as both bonded interfaces then had unique mac addresses.  Keepalived can know properly tell which server is the master and which one is the backup.

Thanks for all the help,

Leo